# Proving $ x^T(I_d-11^T/d)x \ge 0 $

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite, projection-matrices

I am trying to prove the following inequality:

$$
x^T(I_d-11^T/d)x \ge 0
$$

where $d$ is a non-negative integer, $I_d$ a $d\times d$ identity matrix and $1$ a $d \times 1$ vector composed of ones. I can prove this by using the lemma that for any real symmetric $d \times d$ matrix $A$ the following holds:

$$
\lambda_{(1)} \le \frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx} \le \lambda_{(d)}
$$

where $\lambda_{(1)}$ is the smallest and $\lambda_{(d)}$ the largest eigenvalue. Combining this in the above equation one can show (if I am not mistaken) that

$$
0 \le x^T(I_d-11^T/d)x \le x^Tx
$$

which proves the semi-positive definiteness.

Are there any more intuitive ways to prove this without the appeal to this lemma?

Comment: The matrix $I_d-11^T/d$ is a projection matrix (to the plane $\sum_{k=1}^d x_k=0$ specifically). So this is an instance of the fact that projection matrices are positive semi-definite. To see why this should be true, consider the angle between a vector and its vector projection onto a given plane.

Comment: @Semiclassical very good comment that could have been an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  Let $v$ denote the unit-vector $1/\sqrt{d}$.  Then
$$
(I - 11^T/d) = (I - vv^T)
$$
It follows that
$$
x^T(I - 11^T/d)x = 
x^T(I - vv^T)x^T = x^Tx - (x^Tv)^2 =\\
\|x\|^2 - |\langle x,v \rangle|^2
$$
and by Cauchy-Schwarz, this must be non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\mathrm P := \frac{1}{d} 1_d 1_d^\top = \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{d}} 1_d \right) \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{d}} 1_d \right)^\top$$

is a symmetric, rank-$1$ (projection) matrix whose eigenvalues are $1$ and $0$, with multiplicities $1$ and $d-1$, respectively. Thus, $\mathrm I_d - \mathrm P$ is a symmetric (projection) matrix whose eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$, with multiplicities $1$ and $d-1$, respectively. Hence, matrix $\mathrm I_d - \mathrm P$ is **positive semidefinite** and

$$\mathrm x^\top \left( \mathrm I_d - \mathrm P \right) \,\mathrm x \geq 0$$

holds for all $\mathrm x \in \mathbb R^d$.